# What is an Acceptable Data Size to be Transfered using a Hidden Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wcf, silverlight

I have an ASP.NET web-forms application which is integrated with a Silverlight component. The communication between the two is done using WCF services. I want to transfer data (string) from the server to Silverlight. The size of the data is guaranteed to be less than 160 KB. I have two scenarios:

1. I can write my data to an xml file on the server and then access it and consume it from silverlight (I will need to create a virtual directory on the server in order to get an http access to the xml file from silverlight). If I choose to do that, I can use LINQ to XML in order to smoothly/gradually consume the xml file (without loading everything at once)
2. I can simply place my data in a hidden field in the aspx page and then I can access it easily from Silverlight.

Obviously, the second scenario is a lot easier, and also easier to maintain than the first scenario.

The question is: which of the two scenario will I choose? (maybe a third option I'm not aware of?)
Will using the second schenario cause a bottleneck? perhaps on the long term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 160k will only make one trip from the server to the client, then I see no need to use anything more than a hidden field.

If the page were going to be "posted back", so that the 160k would also go back to the server and then maybe back to the client again, then I would use a simple service to get the data from the server to the client, once. That service could be a SOAP service using WCF, or a Web API service. Since you're using Silverlight, it might be convenient to have the service send XML to the client, and the Silverlight code could then easily parse the data using `XDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

> transfer data (string) from the server to Silverlight.

One way would be to use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to transfer the data from the server to a Silverlight client. The setup IMHO is less intense and the communication channel could be used for a continuous line of communication as needed.

---

Since no programs exist in a vacuum...isn't there a shared database? If so have the page send its information to the database instead, to be read by the Silverlight app.

Comment: Why SignalR, and not a less complex Web API service returning XML or even JSON?

Comment: I don't have any real-time scenario here. Why use SignalR?

Comment: @yazanpro It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve..if you want a startup message to a Silverlight client, use the startup javascript to pass in a one-time message.

Comment: Even if the communication needed to be interactive (on button press, for instance), why use SignalR instead of something simpler?

Comment: yes a message. But it's almost 160KB of size. Is this fine?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I may have missed the OP's intent...if there is something simpler, I agree use that.

Comment: Let me clarify, I want to transfer a list of strings. I can either place them in an XML or I can transfer them as comma separated values in a string using a hidden field. The total number of characters is roughly 163000

Comment: @yazanpro see my comment about database transfer.